# How can I configure the OptaPlanner to restart only certain solver phases after ProblemFactChange?

Tags: optaplanner

In my OptaPlanner-based app I would like to use a ProblemFactChange, and according to https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.13.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#problemFactChange it will restart all solver phases.

The problem is a partitioned search phase that I don't want to restart - the solver should proceed to the next phase (CH) and then to a local search phase.

Is it possible to make it work somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting use case. My first thought would be to use a custom Termination, but that would still cause the phase startup overhead - and the Termination interface isn't public api.

This is an RFE really - we need to be able to plug in a conditional in the phase config.

Comment: I would like to use PFC for clearing a specific score trap caused by an accumulation type hard constraint. It is relatively easy to identify this score trap during solver operation, but it can not be removed by a custom move nor the solver. This is due to the nature of the constraint - in some specific cases no single move can improve the score for a set of entities. Even a satisfying compound move (that would do the job) can not be easily generated because all entities need to be placed in better places instantly at once. 1/2

Comment: I thought that I could just remove temporarily these entities from the solution, or to be more precise to move them to an uninitialized state using ProblemFactChange. This would force a CH phase to dispatch these entities again - hopefully to better places (or the same places as before in the worst case) 2/2

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to get through that. I created two solver behaviors: the first one removes a partitioned search phase from the solver when it is finished, and the second one restores phase start times in order to preserve termination end.

A base class for behaviors, please note that I use a non public API.
I have placed all classes in the original OptaPlanner's package in order to have access to protected, and package protected classes without the help of reflection.

```java
package org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope

import org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver


/**
 * Base interface for all behaviors
 */
abstract class SolverBehavior<T>(protected val solver: DefaultSolver<T>) {

    abstract fun apply()

    abstract fun unapply()
}
```

The following behavior removes a partitioned search phase from solver phases after it is completed

```java
package org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver

import org.optaplanner.core.impl.partitionedsearch.PartitionedSearchPhase
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleListener
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractStepScope
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.SolverBehavior
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope


/**
 * Ensures that [org.optaplanner.core.impl.partitionedsearch.PartitionedSearchPhase] run only once
 */
class RunPartitionedSearchOnceBehavior<T>(solver: DefaultSolver<T>) : SolverBehavior<T>(solver) {

    private var solverStartCount: Int = 0

    private val isFirstSolverCycle: Boolean get() = solverStartCount <= 1

    override fun apply() {
        registerForSolverEvents()
    }

    override fun unapply() {
        unregisterFromSolverEvents()
    }

    private fun registerForSolverEvents() {
        solver.addPhaseLifecycleListener(phaseLifecycleListener)
    }

    private fun unregisterFromSolverEvents() {
        solver.removePhaseLifecycleListener(phaseLifecycleListener)
    }

    private fun handleSolverStart() {
        incrementSolverStartCount()
        removePartitionedSearchPhasesIfNecessary()
    }

    private fun removePartitionedSearchPhasesIfNecessary() {
        if (!isFirstSolverCycle) {
            removePartitionedSearchPhases()
        }
    }

    private fun removePartitionedSearchPhases() {
        val phaseListIterator = solver.phaseList.iterator()
        for (phase in phaseListIterator) {
            if (phase is PartitionedSearchPhase) {
                phaseListIterator.remove()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun incrementSolverStartCount() {
        solverStartCount++
    }


    private val phaseLifecycleListener = object : PhaseLifecycleListener<T> {
        override fun solvingStarted(solverScope: DefaultSolverScope<T>) = handleSolverStart()

        override fun phaseStarted(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>) {}

        override fun stepStarted(stepScope: AbstractStepScope<T>) {}

        override fun solvingEnded(solverScope: DefaultSolverScope<T>) {}

        override fun phaseEnded(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>) {}

        override fun stepEnded(stepScope: AbstractStepScope<T>) {}
    }
}
```

The following behavior (enclosed in a Kotlin file) restores start times for all phases in order to preserve their termination time.

```java
package org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope

import org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.scope.ConstructionHeuristicPhaseScope
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.scope.LocalSearchPhaseScope
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleListener
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope
import java.lang.IllegalStateException
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger


private var AbstractPhaseScope<*>.startDate
    get() = Date(startingSystemTimeMillis)
    set(value) {
        startingSystemTimeMillis = value.time
    }

private data class PhaseScopeId constructor(private val phaseClass: Class<*>, private val phaseIndex: Int)

/**
 * When solver restarts it restores phase's start time information in order to preserve termination times.
 * This helps smooth [org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.ProblemFactChange] execution
 */
class PreservePhaseStartTimeBehavior<T>(solver: DefaultSolver<T>) : SolverBehavior<T>(solver) {

    private var solverStartCount: Int = 0

    private var startedPhasesCounters: MutableMap<Class<out AbstractPhaseScope<T>>, AtomicInteger> = mutableMapOf()

    private val isFirstSolverCycle: Boolean get() = solverStartCount <= 1

    private val phasesStartDates: MutableMap<PhaseScopeId, Date> = mutableMapOf()

    private val startTimePreservationPhaseIds: MutableSet<PhaseScopeId> = mutableSetOf()

    fun addLocalSearchPhaseStartTimePreservation(solverPhaseIndex: Int) {
        startTimePreservationPhaseIds.add(PhaseScopeId(LocalSearchPhaseScope::class.java, solverPhaseIndex))
    }

    fun addConstructionHeuristicPhaseStartTimePreservation(solverPhaseIndex: Int) {
        startTimePreservationPhaseIds.add(PhaseScopeId(ConstructionHeuristicPhaseScope::class.java, solverPhaseIndex))
    }

    override fun apply() {
        registerForSolverEvents()
    }

    override fun unapply() {
        unregisterFromSolverEvents()
    }

    private fun registerForSolverEvents() {
        solver.addPhaseLifecycleListener(phaseLifecycleListener)
    }

    private fun unregisterFromSolverEvents() {
        solver.removePhaseLifecycleListener(phaseLifecycleListener)
    }

    private fun handleSolverStart() {
        incrementSolverStartCount()
        resetPhaseStartCounters()
    }

    private fun handlePhaseStarted(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>) {
        incrementPhaseStartCount(phaseScope)
        savePhaseStartTimeIfNecessary(phaseScope)
        restorePhaseStartTimeIfNecessary(phaseScope)
    }

    private fun savePhaseStartTimeIfNecessary(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>) {
        if (isFirstSolverCycle) {
            phasesStartDates[getPhaseIdForStartedPhase(phaseScope)] = phaseScope.startDate
        }
    }

    private fun restorePhaseStartTimeIfNecessary(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>) {
        if (!isFirstSolverCycle) {
            getPhaseIdForStartedPhase(phaseScope).let { phaseScopeId ->
                if (phaseScopeId in startTimePreservationPhaseIds) {
                    restorePhaseStartTime(phaseScope, phaseScopeId)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun restorePhaseStartTime(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>, phaseScopeId: PhaseScopeId) {
        phaseScope.startDate = phasesStartDates[phaseScopeId]
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("No preserved start date for phase scope: $phaseScopeId")
    }

    private fun incrementSolverStartCount() {
        solverStartCount++
    }

    private fun resetPhaseStartCounters() = startedPhasesCounters.clear()

    private fun incrementPhaseStartCount(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>) {
        getStartedPhaseCounterForPhase(phaseScope).incrementAndGet()
    }

    private fun getStartedPhaseCounterForPhase(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>): AtomicInteger {
        return startedPhasesCounters.getOrPut(phaseScope::class.java) { AtomicInteger(-1) }
    }

    private fun getPhaseIdForStartedPhase(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>): PhaseScopeId {
        return PhaseScopeId(phaseScope::class.java, getStartedPhaseCounterForPhase(phaseScope).get())
    }

    private val phaseLifecycleListener = object : PhaseLifecycleListener<T> {
        override fun solvingStarted(solverScope: DefaultSolverScope<T>) = handleSolverStart()

        override fun phaseStarted(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>) = handlePhaseStarted(phaseScope)

        override fun stepStarted(stepScope: AbstractStepScope<T>) {}

        override fun solvingEnded(solverScope: DefaultSolverScope<T>) {}

        override fun phaseEnded(phaseScope: AbstractPhaseScope<T>) {}

        override fun stepEnded(stepScope: AbstractStepScope<T>) {}
    }
}
```